# Digits on 14 segment display are mirrored one to another

Tags: 7segmentdisplay, 74hc595, stm

I have a synth device using 2-digit 14-segment display, a Mutable Yarns Clone. [The PCB design is here.](https://github.com/pichenettes/eurorack/tree/master/yarns/hardware_design/pcb)

It uses an STM32F103CBT6. I flashed it via JTAG without any issues.

the display is driven by a pair of 74HC595D ICs. I'm attaching schematic of this part of the device.

DISP_SCK, DISP_EN, DISP_SER, DISP_CHAR0, DISP_CHAR1 goes straight to the controller.

Everything is working great except for the fact that digits are "mirrored" one to each other. Like when I have 1 on the left digit, it is also displayed on right one with 1/2 brightness. The same goes for right digit, its mirrored reflection is overlayed with the left digit.

It seems that device is working fine except for the mentioned display problem.

There are no obvious bad solder joints, flux is cleaned, firmware is open-sourced and tested, I can't think of it as a problem.

Link to firmware is [here](https://github.com/pichenettes/eurorack/blob/master/yarns/drivers/display.cc)

What should I check? Any directions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are the ``DISP_CHAR0`` and ``DISP_CHAR1`` signals driven by the ``STM32F103CBT6`` firmware? My guess is that the ``DISP_CHAR0`` and ``DISP_CHAR1`` are not correctly synchronised with the output of the ``74HC595D`` leading to incorrect multiplexing of the two characters on the display. Can you edit the question to include either the firmware source code, or a link to it.

Comment: `DISP_CHAR0, DISP_CHAR1 goes straight to the controller` 14 segments leave two open outputs from two 8-bit SIPOs. Then again, it would seem wise to shut off the current display module before registering the segment values for the next.

Comment: Thanks! Well i'm not that used to STM code (never actually learned that) but i think it is here - https://github.com/pichenettes/eurorack/blob/master/yarns/drivers/display.cc

Comment: The only difference which i actually have is that original BOM lists green 14segment ([here](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/kingbright/PDC54-11GWA/17506602?s=N4IgTCBcDaIAoBEDCBWALAWgIxYOIHUBBEAXQF8g)), and i have different one because green wasn't stocked at the time of a purchase. I have [this one](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/kingbright/PDC54-11SURKWA/16602198). But i personally think it can't be the matter...

Comment: is there any reason in resoldering multiplexers? I have some stock so i can replace them...

Comment: @greybeard yes of course. I can make video recording, i found place where there is some numeric parameter set so it changes numbers from 1 to 99. This works same way for both digits (of course i can make a vido of this) Again, this module firmware is used hundreds of times in different Yarns and i didn't found any notice of such bug in Yarns building threads... I will try to play with code a bit in firmware but i doubt it can be the reason

Comment: sorry for the mess! I've messed up transistors for DISP_CHAR lines. Which resulted in completely opposite masking of characters... Thanks everyone! For your ideas

Answer (score 1):

This is so stupid... I messed transistors. Instead of MMBT3904 i've soldered MMBT3906. Which resulted in exactly opposite character selection

Resoldering solved issue completely.